# How to disable Build Analyzer in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Starting with Android Studio 4.0 and the corresponding Android Gradle Plugin, Build Analyzer is available and it runs on each build. Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: Did you find solution to this question? On my new laptop Build Analyzer simply delays a lot app startup during debugging...

Comment: Also posted to Android Studio issue tracker, hope for some useful answer from there: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212373754